# How do you find parallel and perpendicular vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given the vectors $v$ and $w$, write $v = v_\parallel + v_\perp$, where $v_\parallel$ is parallel to $w$, and $v_\perp$ is perpendicular to $w$:

$a) \ v = (2, 3, -7) \ ; \  w = (1,-2,-5)$

$b) \ v = (-3, 1, 2) \ ; \ w = (8,5,-3)$

I found this in an old midterm and I'm not sure how to progress. I know that to find a perpendicular vector the dot product must be $0$ and that a parallel vector a multiple of the vector. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have written the hints:

$v_{||}=\lambda w$ for some number $\lambda$, and $ v-v_{||} = v_\perp\ ( \perp w)$, so we have
$$(v-\lambda w)\cdot w = 0$$
Now find $\lambda$.